# How to get unique dataframe rows based on multiple keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have a dataframe called 'df1':

```
Name Type Destination Data1 Data2
Bob   Car         NY   asdf  dsfg
Liz   Car         NY   asdf  dsfg
```

And another called 'df2':

```
Name Type Destination Data1 Data2
Bob  Train         LA   asdf  dsfg
Liz   Car          NY   asdf  dsfg
```

I want to combine them together based on 3 values to form a 'key': Name, Type, Destination to end up with:

```
Name Type Destination
Bob   Car         NY
Bob Train         LA
Liz   Car         NY
```

Where there are no repeats and the row with Bob, Train, LA... is added since it is a unique entry.

So far I have:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df1.Name, df2.Name]).drop_duplicates().sort_values(ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

but that only works when trying to combine a unique list based off a singular key.

Comment: @Sushanth there is not a `subset` parameter for [`pandas.Series.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) and `pd.concat`, in this case, returns a series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), which return Boolean Series denoting duplicate rows.

  - The entire row is used to determine duplicates.
  - Returns `True` for all the duplicated rows, so to keep the non-duplicate rows, use `~`, which is (`NOT`).
- If only specific columns are wanted in the output, they must be specified with `.iloc` or `df1[['Name', 'Type', 'Destination']]` or they can be dropped after using `concat`.

```py
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Name': ['Bob', 'Liz'], 'Type': ['Car', 'Car'], 'Destination': ['NY', 'NY'], 'Data1': ['asdf', 'asdf'], 'Data2': ['dsfg', 'dsfg']}
data2 = {'Name': ['Bob', 'Liz'], 'Type': ['Train', 'Car'], 'Destination': ['LA', 'NY'], 'Data1': ['asdf', 'asdf'], 'Data2': ['dsfg', 'dsfg']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# concat all the desired rows
dfc = pd.concat([df1.iloc[:, :3], df2.iloc[:, :3]])

# drop the duplicated row
dfc = dfc[~dfc.duplicated()]

# display(dfc)

  Name   Type Destination
0  Bob    Car          NY
1  Liz    Car          NY
0  Bob  Train          LA
```

### Option 2

- The `subset` parameter of [`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates) allows for specifying which columns to use when checking for duplicates.

```py
dfc = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['Name', 'Type', 'Destination'])

# display(dfc)

  Name   Type Destination Data1 Data2
0  Bob    Car          NY  asdf  dsfg
1  Liz    Car          NY  asdf  dsfg
0  Bob  Train          LA  asdf  dsfg
```

Comment: Oops, makes sense. Thanks!